# Android layout, stretch certain parts of the layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm making a little music app.
I`m trying to make my layout as flexible as possible, for this example this means i want to scale up the albumart and leave the rest (buttons for control, title,..) unscaled.

- 1) is this "good practice"? may i leave the other controls umscaled?
- 2) how to do this? Which atributes? i have uploaded a sample screenshot here of the design http://www.flickr.com/photos/59647462@N08/7038458497/

for your info this is highlevel overview of my xml:

```
   <linearlayout>
    /// Title
    </linearlayout

   <framelayout>
    /// albumart | resize me block
   </framelayout>


   <relativelayout>
   /// subfooter
   </relativelayout>

   <linearlayout>
   /// footer
   </linearlayout>     
  </linearlayout>
```

extra question: how to stick the footer to bottem of page? is this possible without relative layout?

thank you in advance, hope it's clear what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you dont want to use relative layout... but if you use a relative layout.. I think it will be easy...[Here is an example with three fields..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868882/android-xml-layout-how-to-fill-content-to-the-entire-screen-keeping-the-footer/9869139#9869139)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout`. Use the `layout_weight` & `weightSum` values for stretching. Example Here -

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

> 1) is this "good practice"? may i leave the other controls umscaled?

I think that this depends on how you prefer your app to look on different devices.  Personally I would rather use weights to scale proportionatly. (e.g. top and bottom taking up 25% each and the center section could be 50%).  This would avoid controls becoming too small when moving from one resolution to the next.

> 2) how to do this? Which atributes? i have uploaded a sample screenshot here of the design http://www.flickr.com/photos/59647462@N08/7038458497/

I agree with Shaiful.  Linear layout would provide a good layout for your design.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, your controls should not scale but they must handle screen configurations changes and different screen densities.

2)The most useful attributes to manage that are:

```
android:layout_width
android:layout_height
```

with some

```
android:padding
android:layout_margin
```

To make it look good

Generally make sure your UI handles:

- Screen size changes. For instance they change if you go from portrait mode to landscape mode.
- Screen densities. Phones have different screen resolutions so make sure your images and controls scale properly (use dp instead of px).